# How to see Websphere application Server (WAS) responses

Tags: http, logging, websphere, websphere-7

On occasion Post request sent to our WAS leave the browser (IE) waiting for a response forever (until manually cancelled - e.g. by closing the browser).

Looking at the Trace and SystemOut logs on WAS everything looks fine. in the http_error log we can see the Get and Post requests but not the responses (even for successful requests). Is there a way to see the responses, or at least when they are sent? We need this to ensure that a response is being sent to the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would issue a **SIGQUIT** signal to the Websphere process in order to produce a javacore, i.e. a **threadump**, in order to see what my **WebContainer threads** are actually doing.

Try running a `kill -3 <WAS process ID>` as root in a unix platform or invoke `DumpThreads` [through wsadmin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384926) if running on a Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable trace for servlet container. This is done by setting trace string to `*=info:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all:HTTPChannel=all:GenericBNF=all`

[Setting up a trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254706)